# Use NVM in Ruby script - keep context between calls

Tags: ruby, node.js, nvm

I search a way keeping context between two `IO.popen` calls.

There is what I am trying:

```
IO.popen(". $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm use 6") do |io| 
  io.each do |line| 
    puts line 
  end 
end
Now using node v6.9.4 (npm v3.10.10)
#<IO:(closed)>

IO.popen("node -v") do |io| 
  io.each do |line| 
    puts line 
  end 
end
v4.2.4
#<IO:(closed)>
```

Note from nvm developer (explaining the `. $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh`):

> Please note that which nvm will not work, since nvm is a sourced shell function, not an executable binary.

Someone got an idea ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Each `popen` launches a subprocess, and environment is always restricted to current process and its subprocesses. Why can't you do everything inside one `bash` subprocess?

Comment: I'm in a fastlane process, so, I wan't to unify our tasks using a single `before all -> nvm use x` then use my tasks without redefine him each time. I was thinking about a solution with a `popen("execute", context)` or create an Instance of IO.popen to reuse. But I am a real newbie with ruby :s